# Cannot get Symfony to work?

Tags: php, symfony, installation, symfony-2.5

This is my first time using Symfony framework. I have installed the framework using Composer. It has installed properly. It didn't give me any errors or even a warning. Then I generated a bundle.

Then I ran the server using `php app/console server:run`. The terminal showed me the server was running on 127.0.0.1:8000. But when I write 127.0.0.1:8000 it doesn't show me anything, the browser just keeps loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try: `php app/check.php`

and remember, you need to give permissions in **app/cache** and **app/logs** folders (chmod 777 app/cache app/logs, but this way isn't the correct form in production)

in your **app_dev.php** put the develop environment to **true** and in your **app.php** put the production environment to **false**

Comment: If I run php app/console server:run, and then try to go to localhost:8000, what should come on my screen?

Comment: I never use this command, I have my apache server UP, and I go to my var/www/sf2_project/web/app_dev.php
I'm using a 2.0.20 version of sf2 and this command doesn't exist

Comment: thank you for your answer, seems like there was already a process running on 8000 port. Once I killed it and ran the command again it worked perfectly. :)